# strip the last and first character from a String

Tags: sed, awk

Is fairly easy to strip the first and last character from a string using `awk`/`sed`?

Say I have this string
`( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 )`

I would like to strip parentheses from it.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

sed way

```
$ echo '( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 )' | sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/'
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

awk way

```
$ echo '( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 )' | awk '{print substr($0, 2, length($0) - 2)}'
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

POSIX sh way

```
$ var='( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 )'; var="${var#?}"; var="${var%?}"; echo "$var"
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

bash way

```
$ var='( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 )'; echo "${var:1: -1}"
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

---

If you use `bash` then use the bash way.

If not, prefer the posix-sh way. It is faster than loading `sed` or `awk`.

Other than that, you may also be doing other text processing, that you can combine with this, so depending on the rest of the script you may benefit using `sed` or `awk` in the end.

---

> why doesn't this work? `sed '..' s_res.temp > s_res.temp` ?

This does not work, as the redirection `>` will truncate the file before it is read. 
To solve this you have some choices:

1. what you really want to do is *edit* the file. `sed` is a *stream editor* not a file editor.
   `ed` though, is a file editor (the standard one too!). So, use `ed`:

   ```
    $ printf '%s\n' "%s/^.\(.*\).$/\1/" "." "wq" | ed s_res.temp
   ```
2. use a temporary file, and then `mv` it to replace the old one.

   ```
    $ sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/' s_res.temp > s_res.temp.temp
    $ mv  s_res.temp.temp  s_res.temp
   ```
3. use `-i` option of `sed`. This only works with GNU-sed, as `-i` is **not** POSIX and GNU-only:

   ```
   $ sed -i 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/' s_res.temp
   ```
4. abuse the shell (not recommended really):

   ```
    $ (rm test; sed 's/XXX/printf/' > test) < test
   ```

---

On Mac OS X (latest version 10.12 - Sierra) `bash` is stuck to version `3.2.57` which is quite old. One can always install `bash` using [`brew`](https://brew.sh/) and get version `4.x` which includes the substitutions needed for the above to work.

There is a collection of bash versions and respective changes, compiled on the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges)

Comment: I like to use the `sed`. One question, though, why doesn't this work? `sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/'  s_res.temp > s_res.temp` ?

Comment: because the redirection truncates the file before it is read. I'll update my answer for this.

Comment: With OS X Yosemite (GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14) to be exact), I get `-bash:  -1: substring expression < 0` for the Bash version. The following does work though: `var='( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 )'; echo "${var:1: ${#var}-2}"`

Comment: On Mac OS X (latest version 10.12 - Sierra) `bash` is stuck to version `3.2.57` which is quite old. One can always install `bash` using [`brew`](https://brew.sh/) and get version `4.x` which includes the substitutions needed for the above to work.

Answer (score 6):

To remove the first and last characters from a given string, I like this `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/.$//'
#         ^^          ^^
# first char          last char
```

See an example:

```
sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/.$//' <<< "(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 2):

If I want to remove the First (1) character and the last two (2) characters using sed.

Input  `"t2.large",`

Output `t2.large`

```
sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/..$//'
```

`

Answer (score 1):

And also a perl way:

```
perl -pe 's/^.|.$//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 )' | awk NF RS='[()]'
```

---

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Two times strip first character from the string and reverse the string twice:

```
echo "( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 )" | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2- | rev
```