# Unable to grep with value having space in linux inside a for loop

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, grep

I have declared an array

```
declare -a kernel_parms=("'kernel.shmmax ':4294967295:IBM" "'kernel.shmseg ':2048:AT" "'kernel.shmmni ':2048:BT" "'kernel.sem ':1024:IBM" "'kernel.semaem ':16384:IBM" "'kernel.semvmx ':32767:IBM" "'kernel.semmap ':1026:AT" "'kernel.semmnu ':16384:IBM" "'kernel.semume ':256:IBM" "'kernel.msgmni ':50:AT" "'kernel.msgmap ':1024:BT" "'kernel.msgmax ':4096:AT" "'kernel.msgmnb ':4096:AT")
```

I am running a for loop in linux

```
for ((i=0;i< ${#kernel_parms[@]};i++)); 
do  
    echo "Param is" + "${kernel_parms[$i]}"
    parm=`echo "${kernel_parms[$i]}" | gawk -F: '{print $1}'`
    echo "${kernel_parms[$i]}"
    echo $parm
    sysctl -a | grep -i "$parm"
done
```

For first entry in array parm is 'kernel.shmmax ' but grep does not return any result inside for loop but if I perform grep standalone then I do get results

```
# sysctl -a | grep -i 'kernel.shmmax '
  kernel.shmmax = 18446744073692774399
```

Output of for loop is

```
Param is + 'kernel.shmmax ':4294967295:IBM
'kernel.shmmax ':4294967295:IBM
'kernel.shmmax '
Param is + 'kernel.shmseg ':2048:AT
'kernel.shmseg ':2048:AT
'kernel.shmseg '
Param is + 'kernel.shmmni ':2048:BT
'kernel.shmmni ':2048:BT
'kernel.shmmni '
Param is + 'kernel.sem ':1024:IBM
'kernel.sem ':1024:IBM
'kernel.sem '
Param is + 'kernel.semaem ':16384:IBM
'kernel.semaem ':16384:IBM
'kernel.semaem '
Param is + 'kernel.semvmx ':32767:IBM
'kernel.semvmx ':32767:IBM
'kernel.semvmx '
Param is + 'kernel.semmap ':1026:AT
'kernel.semmap ':1026:AT
'kernel.semmap '
Param is + 'kernel.semmnu ':16384:IBM
'kernel.semmnu ':16384:IBM
'kernel.semmnu '
Param is + 'kernel.semume ':256:IBM
'kernel.semume ':256:IBM
'kernel.semume '
Param is + 'kernel.msgmni ':50:AT
'kernel.msgmni ':50:AT
'kernel.msgmni '
Param is + 'kernel.msgmap ':1024:BT
'kernel.msgmap ':1024:BT
'kernel.msgmap '
Param is + 'kernel.msgmax ':4096:AT
'kernel.msgmax ':4096:AT
'kernel.msgmax '
Param is + 'kernel.msgmnb ':4096:AT
'kernel.msgmnb ':4096:AT
'kernel.msgmnb '
```

Why grep is not returning any matches inside for loop? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sagar

Comment: Don't use an index to iterate over the array.  Use the pattern: `for x in "${a[@]}"; do echo "$x"; done`

Comment: sysctl -a | grep -i "$parm"; still does not give any output

Comment: The missing quotes on the `echo` may be hiding a whitespace issue. With `-F:`, `gawk` will likely be leaving whitespace in `$parm`.  You should try `echo "$parm" | xxd` to see what is actually in `parm`, and also try `grep -i $parm` (without quotes), but that's a hack.

Comment: Yes it is leaving whitespace and I actually want whitespaces .. is there any solution so it will work with whitespaces

Comment: Add a line `set -x` at the beginning of your script (after the `#!...` line of course) and show the output in your question.

Comment: The problem "$parm" contains quotes 'kernel.msgmap ' and it gets searched with quotes .. but the output of "sysctl -a" does not have quotes

Comment: I want to have space but doesn't want to have quotes

Comment: Is there a requirement to have the quotes in the array values? Could you change it to either `declare -a kernel_parms=("kernel.shmmax :4294967295:IBM" ...)` or `declare -a kernel_parms=("kernel.shmmax:4294967295:IBM" ...)` You could append the space (and the equals sign) for the `grep` command like `grep -i "$parm "` or  `grep -i "$parm ="`. Note that `grep` matches regular expressions where the dot `.` means "any character", so the string `kernelXmsgmax` would match the pattern `kernel.msgmax`. Use `fgrep` instead of `grep` if you want to match exact strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strip the last and first character from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362142/strip-the-last-and-first-character-from-a-string)

Using the above answer I am removing first and last character of variable which are quotes in the command and its showing results now

Modified inside for loop to

```
sysctl -a | grep -i "${parm:1:-1}";
```

from

```
sysctl -a | grep -i "$parm";
```

and it worked like charm