# How to remove first & last character in bash string

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

MA=$(bt-device -l | cut -d " " -f 3)
MAC=${MA:1: -1}
bluetoothctl connect $MAC
```

Expected Result

```
98:9E:63:18:00:88
```

Actual result

```
(98:9E:63:18:00:88
```

Comment: What is output of `bt-device -l` ?

Comment: What's the original value of `MA`? `MA="(98:9E:63:18:00:88)"; echo "${MA:1: -1}"` strips both parentheses as seemingly expected.

Comment: Denny’s Tunez (98:9E:63:18:00:88)

Comment: I suspect your value of `MA` has a leading space or something, so that `(` is actually the *second* character in the string.

Comment: you was correct chepner thank you very much there must be a leading space running as hoped now

Comment: `echo 'Denny’s Tunez (98:9E:63:18:00:88)' | grep -Eo '([0-9A-F]{2}:){5}[0-9A-F]{2}'`?

Comment: @AzureRuby Please update your question with the value of MA (use quotes) so we know if there are spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [strip the last and first character from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362142/strip-the-last-and-first-character-from-a-string)

Comment: Amazing so how is this question "does not appear to be about programming"?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
s="(98:9E:63:18:00:88)"

s="${s/#?/}"  # remove first character
s="${s/%?/}"  # remove last character

echo "$s"
```

Output:

```
98:9E:63:18:00:88
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion:

1. offset and length

```
echo ${MA:1: -1}
```

2. prefix and suffix removal

```
tmp=${MA#(}
echo ${tmp%)}
```

3. parameter matching

```
tmp=${MA/#\(}
echo ${tmp/%\)}
```

Another approach is to:

4. whitelist what you do want

```
echo "$MA" | tr -dC '[0-9A-F:]'
```

Answer (score 1):

A few alternatives:

```
$ echo 'Denny’s Tunez (98:9E:63:18:00:88)' | sed -En 's/^[^(]*\(([^)]*)\).*/\1/p'
98:9E:63:18:00:88

$ echo 'Denny’s Tunez (98:9E:63:18:00:88)' | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1
98:9E:63:18:00:88

$ echo 'Denny’s Tunez (98:9E:63:18:00:88)' | awk -F'[)(]' '{print $2}'
98:9E:63:18:00:88

$ echo 'Denny’s Tunez (98:9E:63:18:00:88)' | grep -Eow '(..)(:..){5}'
98:9E:63:18:00:88

$ x='Denny’s Tunez (98:9E:63:18:00:88)'
$ y="${x//*\(/}"
$ y="${y//\)*}"
$ echo $y
98:9E:63:18:00:88
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` it can be done in a single step:

```bash
s='Denny’s Tunez (98:9E:63:18:00:88)'
echo "$s" | sed -E 's/.* \(|)//g'

98:9E:63:18:00:88
```

So for your example you can use:

```
mac=$(bt-device -l | sed -E 's/.* \(|)//g')
```